# How to generate transient errors for testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, ef-core-2.2

I have implemented custom retry strategy on an API which is in .NET Core 2.2. Retry strategy should work only for transient errors from the database(Azure SQL). How can I generate transient errors, to test this feature?

Comment: Generate a random number and throw an error if that number meets a given condition?

Comment: @David just suggested to add a random number to a unit test without any guidance or caveats whatsoever.  ..something that hundreds of people easily implement incorrectly because they don't set a random seed and wind up with unpredictable unit tests and don't know what the expected results should be.  Better suggestion:  mock and return error on first n calls call and success on (n+1)th call.  Consumer should retry. N+1 times.

Comment: Don't know who you have implemented this, but design for test is an important concept when you want to do unit testing. Separate the retry strategy code from the API client code. In that way you could mock the client to the Azure SQL and throw what ever exception you want. If you want I can give you a code example.

Comment: @David Unit tests should be repeatable and consistent, any kind of 'randomness' is bad.  It's very easy to setup unit tests to 'fail' a particular call once or twice, followed by a 'success', therefore testing the 'transient' nature of the test being done.

Comment: @Vikas How have you implemented your custom strategy?  Using Polly, or something else?

Comment: Can you update this to include examples of which exceptions you consider transient?

Comment: sorry for late reply. @Neil by overriding 'GetNextDelay' method in 'ExecutionStrategy' class.

Comment: @Michael great! please share how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code, but this is one solution. The idea is to separate the retry logic from the actual action that needs to be retried, so that each can be tested.

A static RetryHandler could also work, but it depends on your need.

Psedo code, does not compile.

```
public RetryHandler : IRetryHandler
{
    private static List<Type> transientErros = new List<Type>
    {
        typeof(TimeoutException),
        typeof(SomeotherExceptionThatRequiresRetry),
    }

    public void RetryOnTransientError(Action action, int attempts = 3)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < attempts; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
                return;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                if(transientErros.Contains(e.GetType())
                    continue;

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    private IMyDbContext context;
    private IRetryHandler retryHandler;

    public Repository(IMyDbContext context, IRetryHandler retryHandler)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.retryHandler = retryHandler;
    }

    public void InsertUser(User user)
    {
        retryHandler.RetryOnTransientError(() => DoInsertUser(user));
    }

    private void DoInsertUser(User user)
    {
        // insert logic
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

[Test]
public void InsertUserRetriesOnTransientError()
{
    // Arrange
    var contextMock = new Mock<IMyDbContext>();
    var repository = new Repository(contextMock);
    var user = CreateUser();

    contextMock.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Throws<TransientException>());

    // Act
    Assert.Throws<TransientException>(() => repository.InsertUser(user)); 

    // Assert
    // verify SaveChanges() was called 3 times
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree with this. Is there a class that catches all kinds of transient errors? So that I can replace <TransientError> placeholder in your code.

Also, I'm overriding ShouldRetryOn method in ExecutionStrategy class. Doc: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.executionstrategy?view=efcore-2.2) . I get exception as method parameter. How should I compare in such situations?

Comment: See if my update helps. I could be more specific if you update your OP with code example of what you are doing.